# How to work with Core Data relationships?

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I have two entities:

```
Patient
- firstName
- lastName
- scheduledAppointments <---->> Appointment

Appointment
- date
- times
- scheduledPatient <<----> Patient
```

Basically I have one Patient with many appointments. How do I set the scheduledPatient in the Appointments entity? I've tried this so far:

```
[self.appointment setScheduledPatient:[self.patientArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

self.appointment.scheduledPatient = [self.patientArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

They work when I'm editing an appointment. But it returns a SIGBRT when I'm adding a new appointment.

Comment: Could you share the crash log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to be correct. 
Therefore I suppose that most likely you have not defined the inverse relation properly in the  .xcdatamodel file.

For what I understand you have a one-to-many relationships. That is, one Patient may have a number of Appointments. Therefore, an appointment belongs to one patient. In order for this relation to be semantically correct, you need to let it know how they relate to each other. In order to do so you need to specify what is the inverse element of each of the elements in the relation. 
In the picture below you can see how a Region may have a number of states, and a state belongs uniquely to a region. Notice the arrow connecting the elements of the relation, how the "many" has a double arrow and the "one" has a single arrow.
[image]

I believe that you most likely forgot to specify this in the xcdatamodel file.

Check out this link for more information:https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html

```
Inverse Relationships
Most relationships are inherently bi-directional. If a Department has a to-many relationship to the Employees that work in a Department, there is an inverse relationship from an Employee to the Department. The major exception is a fetched property, which represents a weak one-way relationship—there is no relationship from the destination to the source (see “Fetched Properties”).

You should typically model relationships in both directions, and specify the inverse relationships appropriately. Core Data uses this information to ensure the consistency of the object graph if a change is made (see “Manipulating Relationships and Object Graph Integrity”). For a discussion of some of the reasons why you might not want to model a relationship in both directions, and some of the problems that might arise if you don’t, see “Unidirectional Relationships.”
```